# Kentico - Insert reusable numbers in text on multiple pages

Tags: kentico

Not sure if the title is clear enough but here's what I want. Throughout my site, I have some numbers that are repeatedly used on multiple pages - such as we're serving 1,000 clients in 80 major cities in the world. Before Kentico, I can store these numbers (1,000 and 80) as constants and can call/insert them onto the page text wherever and whenever I want easily. With Kentico, I'm not sure how to do it yet. Is there something equivalent? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best choice is two use either of these. These are meant for specially the use case you are experiencing.

Both are recommended approaches by Kentico

1. Content blocks - http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/content-blocks
2. Resource strings - https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Working+with+resource+strings

You may also see Jan Hermann's answer - http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/creating-global-text-content

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked. The other suggestion from another person below worked, too, but yours seems to work better in my case. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!! Your answer helped me in resolving a long pending issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this is to [add custom settings](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Adding+custom+website+settings).
Quickest way to accomplish this is to:

1. Open the **Modules** application in the Admin area
2. Edit the `Custom` module
3. Click the Settings tab
4. Create a new settings category by clicking the plus (**+**) button, and name it appropriately.
5. Create a new settings group, and name it appropriately (even "General" will do)
6. Create a settings key for each of your values. **It is important that you use a unique name for the Code name of the settings keys.**

[image: Settings keys]

You can then set the values.

7. Open the **Settings** application, and set the value of your settings key.

[image: Setting the values of the settings keys]

You can then access your settings using macro expressions.
For example, if the "number of clients" settings key has the code name of `CustomSiteClientCount`, the macro expression would be along the lines of:

```
{% Settings.CustomSiteClientsCount %}
```

In your editable text area, this would be:

> We're serving `{% Settings.CustomSiteClientsCount %}` clients in...

Comment: Thanks for your time and detailed response. I tried your suggestion and it  worked, too. The other response that I accepted is more suited to my situation. But it's nice to know different ways to tackle the same problem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a call to action [page type](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K81/Creating+page+types) with a rich text area and or what ever other fields work for you.

Create these items as CTAs in the content tree

You can then [create a widget](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Creating+widgets) which you can drop in a widget zone or into an [rich text area](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Adding+page+content+through+widgets) - this widget would be of a repeater that points to the CTA path in the content tree. Alternatively if you want to display these things in a fixed area on the pages template you can just use the repeater web part.